# Escaping multiple backticks in a sed call

Tags: bash, shell, sed, quoting

I need to perform search and replacement iteratively in several SQL statements:

From:

```
CREATE TABLE `Old_Name` (
```

To:

```
ALTER TABLE `Old_Name` RENAME TO `New_Name`
```

The above query contains backticks `` ` ``. I tried doing the following

```
sed -i -r "s/CREATE TABLE \`$search\` \(/ALTER TABLE \`$search\` RENAME TO \`$replacement\`/g" /query.txt;
```

It creates an enter on the command line instead. But if I add a space behind `$replacement`, it runs normally. But I do not want the space after `New_Name`.

Note, I do not know whether this is actually caused by the backticks or it could be a variable name interpolation problem. Regardless the case, how can I solve this issue?

Comment: Can you provide more details about your script? How do you assign value to `$search` and `$replacement`?

Comment: @Gnouc, the search and replacement strings are extracted from a mapping list similar to [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128129/24509)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To reduce the escaping to the minimum, I suggest to use single quotes with `sed`, like in

```
sed 's/pattern/repl/g'
```

(in single quotes you can freely use the backtick without any fear and without escaping).
If you need to use shell variable in the `sed` script, put together single quotes and double quotes like in the following example

```
var="bbb"
thing=foo
sed 's/aaa'"${var}"'ccc/some'"${thing}"'else/g'
```

that could be better seen as the following concatenation

```
's/aaa' + "${var}" + 'ccc/some' + "${thing}" + 'else/g'
```

Comment: Yes, that's right. The brackets solved it. Thanks!

Comment: I tried to use single quotes, but the `(` is causing problem. Still need to escape the backticks though.

Comment: @QuestionOverflow: in GNU `sed`, if you use the `-r` option, the round parentheses are used for grouping. So don't use `-r` option or alternatively use `\(` for round parentheses.